# Insert Multiple Rows in SQL SERVER using a Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I need to insert multiple rows into another table using a trigger, but it only inserts the last record
I have checked some other posts in stackoverflow and didn't find an Answer,

This is my trigger

```
IF(@TNAEventID IN(1,2,3))       
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Biostar].Cen.WentOutLog    (AutoID, nUserID, nOutDateTime,nOutTNAEvent ,nReaderID) values  (@AutoID,@UseID, @DateTime,@TNAEventID, @ReaderID )
END
else IF(@TNAEventID=0)      
BEGIN
    
    UPDATE Cen.WentOutLog Set  nINDateTime =@DateTime,nInTNAEvent = @TNAEventID  Where AutoID = (Select  top (1) AutoID from Cen.WentOutLog where nINDateTime is null AND  nOutDateTime<@DateTime AND  nUserID=@UseID order by nOutDateTime desc)
END
else
begin
    ....
end
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Since you are assigning values to variables from INSERTED tables, it will only hold last row inserted. To insert all rows you simple need to use: INSERT INTO <TargetTable> SELECT <RequiredColumns> FROM INSERTED

Comment: Same thing can be done with UPDATE to handle multiple rows. You need to use UPDATE statement with JOIN clause, you can find plenty of examples online.

Comment: @Vishal i searched all over the internet but i didn't understood those can you please give create that code for me, according to above query.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code, Insert code is readily usable.

> You might need to change the UPDATE statement as I do not know what is
>   your data:

```
INSERT INTO [Biostar].[Cen].[WentOutLog]
    ([AutoID], [nUserID], [nOutDateTime], [nOutTNAEvent], [nReaderID])
SELECT  [AutoID], [nUserID], [nOutDateTime], [nOutTNAEvent], [nReaderID]
FROM    INSERTED
WHERE   TNAEventID IN (1, 2, 3)

UPDATE  W
FROM    [Cen].[WentOutLog]
SET     W.[nINDateTime] = I.[DateTime],
        W.[nInTNAEvent] = I.[TNAEventID]
INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON W.[AutoID] = I.[AutoID]
WHERE   I.[TNAEventID] = 0
AND     W.[nINDateTime] IS NULL
AND     W.[nOutDateTime] < I.[DateTime]
AND     W.[nUserID] = I.[UserID]
```

Comment: INSERT Is working fine but im having trouble wit update, i have sub query in Update's where condition, i have used select top(1) but it still saying "Subquery returned more than 1 value"